# How to make 3d camera infinitely rotate around with SDL2 mouse motion?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, camera, sdl-2

I am trying to implement 3D camera mouse rotation. Right now what I can do is only rotate if my mouse is in the bound of the window. What it means is if my window is 1280 width I cannot rotate more if mouse coordinates rich 0 or 1279. I've read that relative mouse should help. It does not work for me though.

before the main loop

```
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(window, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
```

The function that rotates xyz

```
glm::vec3 MouseMotion(float x, float y)
{
    float lastX = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, lastY = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    float pitch = 0.0f, yaw = -90.0f;

    float offsetX = x - lastX;
    float offsetY = lastY - y;
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;

    float sensitivity = 0.3f;

    yaw += offsetX * sensitivity;
    pitch += offsetY * sensitivity;

    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = std::cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * std::cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = std::sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = std::sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * std::cos(glm::radians(pitch));

    //std::cout << "Mouse: " << offsetX << ", " << offsetY << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "YAW AND PITCH: " << yaw << ", " << pitch << std::endl;

    return glm::normalize(front);
}
```

and the event loop

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
        {
            float mouseX = (float)event.motion.x;
            float mouseY = (float)event.motion.y;
            cameraFront = MouseMotion(mouseX, mouseY);
        }
    }
```

it is working, but only if my mouse is in the bound.

Changing to event.motion.xrel and event.motion.yrel do not fix this. It makes it more bugged because my camera shakes, i.e. going a little bit right and get back to center or left and back to center.

How to make my camera move fully, infinitely move around?

Comment: Google "[implementing] mouse look". [Here's](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/16328-implementing-mouse-look/) a nice and simple one to get you started.

Comment: I know how to rotate a camera based on mouse motion. My question is about how to remove a bound that SDL2 mouse motion has got.

Comment: Well, if you had *actually* researched `mouse look` properly, you will have come across the standard method used to overcome this, which is to reset the mouse to a fixed point after every position query.

Comment: I understand. What is actually `prev_mouse_x` because I do not see any declaration on it?

Comment: The "previous" value at each query-reset cycle is always the fixed position that you reset the cursor to. You take the position delta and scale that to angular deltas.

Comment: I do not exactly understand. Could you explain it a little bit more, please?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't understand? It doesn't sound much different to what you are doing already. Basically, when you update the mouse look: 1) query the mouse position, 2) set the mouse position to the fixed point, 3) subtract the fixed point from the queried mouse position to get the movement delta, 4) use these deltas to calculate the changes in camera parameters. Done.

Comment: So, looking up on the code: 1) `float x and float y` in MouseMotion function are mouse position, 2) `lastX and lastY` are fixed points, 3) `offsetX and offsetY` are deltas, 4) `yaw += offsetX * sens and pitch += offsetY * sens` are these values which to use to move camera.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it does not reset the mouse. You don't need the `last(X/Y)` variables. Just set the mouse to a pre-determined point (say the center of the screen).

Comment: I think I get it. for example, 

`float mouseX = event.motion.x;`

`x -= SCREEN_WIDTH / 2` 

and then set the x value?

Comment: No. What is that `X` variable that you are decrementing? Just call `SDL_WarpMouseInWindow` after *every* loop in addition to at the start.

Comment: I could be mouseX instead of just x. That call every loop instead at the beginning changed a lot, but still it is not infinite rotation

Comment: I can't really help you without seeing your code. I could only suggest a solution to your original problem; it is up to you to actually implement and debug it.

Comment: You have got my code up there! If it is not enough there you go: https://pastebin.com/Uva6Aacy

Comment: I see what the problem is. You reset the `pitch` and `yaw` everytime you call  `MouseMotion` (pointing to the line `float pitch = 0.0f, yaw = -90.0f;`). You should move these variables up a scope, or make them static (not recommended, but a quick 'n' easy fix), so that the values are continuous across successive calls.

Comment: I am 100% sure you are not correct. I did it and my camera started panic and weirdly moving around. Also to be sure, I have moved my code which is inside MouseMotion to main loop to not use the function and the result is the same. Doesn't matter if I set it as a static or outside the loop.

Comment: Before you jump to the conclusion that I am completely incorrect, merely based on the fact that I recognized a flaw in the code which contributes to but did not *directly* solve the entire problem, I suggest you actually *think* about other potential reasons.

Comment: Let's consider the sensitivity value. A typical mouse movement on a typical modern screen may be of 100s or 1000s of pixels long; multiplied by your sensitivity this might give ~500 degrees of movement. Therefore even a relatively *small* mouse movement may result in *several* turns of the camera. Experiment with a range of smaller sensitivities, e.g. 0.001 or 0.0001

Comment: If I set only yaw or yaw and pitch static doesnt matter what only yaw is working. I am pulling mouse down - camera moving right, pulling mouse up - camera moving right too. Sensitivity does not changing anything. I set lastX and lastY, and yaw, and pitch as a global variables and it looks like it is working, I mean the camera does not do weird movement. The bound is much bigger on yaw and pitch, though.

Comment: As I said before, you don't need `last(X/Y)`. What do you mean by "the bound is much bigger"? And "sensitivity does not changing anything"?

Comment: I meant the bound is much lower, even if I do not set a bound for pitch it still is. The sensitivity changes that camera moves slower, but does not fix the issue. `As I said before, you don't need last(X/Y).` without it, it goes crazy at all.

Comment: I feel that at this point I might as well post an answer with my proposed changes clarified in code.

Comment: I do not know man. 2 days ago I read learnopengl camera tutorial and watched Jorge Rodriguez's film about camera and the formula is the same. Maybe I should try glfw for mouse input instead of SDL2. However it is good to learn something new. Unfortunetelly I am new with it and it is hard to debug it.

Comment: SDL is a tried, tested and popular library. Nothing wrong with SDL, only your own code. It's quite possible that you would run into the same problems regardless of which library you use.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments, here is a list of problems:

- You need to call `SDL_WarpMouseInWindow` every time after an `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event to reset the mouse, or it will quickly hit the "bound" you were talking about.
- `pitch` and `yaw` need to be higher in scope than the game loop, or they will be reset every time and you won't be able to achieve "infinite rotation".
- `sensitivity` is *far* too high. A typical mouse movement of ~500 units translates to a ~180 degree turning.

---

Here is an attempt at fixing the above issues, with some code refactoring:

```
glm::vec3 polarVector(float p, float y)
{
    // this form is already normalized
    return glm::vec3(std::cos(y) * std::cos(p),
                     std::sin(p),
                     std::sin(y) * std::cos(p));
}

// clamp pitch to [-89, 89]
float clampPitch(float p)
{
    return p > 89.0f ? 89.0f : (p < -89.0f ? -89.0f : p);   
}

// clamp yaw to [-180, 180] to reduce floating point inaccuracy
float clampYaw(float y)
{
    float temp = (y + 180.0f) / 360.0f;
    return y - ((int)temp - (temp < 0.0f ? 1 : 0)) * 360.0f;
}



int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
    // ...

    // experiment with this
    const float sensitivity = 0.001f; 

    #define CTR_X (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2)
    #define CTR_Y (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)
    #define RESET_MOUSE SDL_WarpMouseInWindow(window, CTR_X, CTR_Y)

    // call once at the start
    RESET_MOUSE;

    // keep outside the loop
    float pitch = 0.0f, yaw = 0.0f;

    while (!quit)
    {
        // ...

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                float deltaX = (float)event.motion.x - CTR_X;
                float deltaY = (float)event.motion.y - CTR_Y;

                yaw = clampYaw(yaw + sensitivity * deltaX);
                pitch = clampPitch(pitch - sensitivity * deltaY);

                // assumes radians input
                cameraFront = polarVector(glm::radians(pitch), glm::radians(yaw));

                // reset *every time*
                RESET_MOUSE;
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM2MqxPoZWw&feature=youtu.be I've been pulling mouse only left.

Comment: Can you test that the `delta(X/Y)` values are as one would expect, by e.g. printing them to a console?

Comment: Delta X is from -640 to +639 and delta Y is from -360 to +359

Comment: I mean that when you pull the mouse in a specific direction, do the corresponding `delta(X/Y)` values seem sensible? E.g. pull to the bottom-left corner, and the values should be like `deltaX < 0, deltaY > 0`

Comment: Ahh apologies as I forgot to convert `yaw/pitch` into radians. Try now.

Comment: Nope, still nothing fixed

Comment: It is not working correctly. I am going to bed. Thanks for any help. I'll read what you think at morning.